# How should I deal with the exception which happened in a catch block?

Tags: java, exception

```
BufferedReader in
       = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     try {
        while((thisLine=in.readLine())!=null){
        ...  
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
                    //in.close();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in the code above, I want to close the read buffer in the catch block.But I find that the function in.close also throws an IOException. It look ugly if I nest another try-catch block in the catch block.So ,what is the correct way to deal with such a problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `finally` block for that. `finally-block` execulated every time unless jvm exits abnormaly.

Java 7 `try-with-resources` statement to automatically close, you need to close resouce stream explicitly,

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
>   or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
>   the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
>   ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
>   object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all
>   objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

[read more on documentaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Example -

```
try(BufferedReader in
       = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
  while((thisLine=in.readLine())!=null){
        ...  
  }
}catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well ,thank  you very much for your recommendation.This is a new feature in java 7 right?It is really the perfect solution for my problem.Many thanks.

Comment: If your are thinking about how to close the input stream properly then it the best way, and yes

Answer (score 1):

Close the resources in a `finally` block, not in a `catch` block.

```
    try 
    {
      // actual code.
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
      // handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
       try
       {
         in.close();
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
          // handle exception
       }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do in [finally block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html),Which is specially meant for cleanup.

From finally block docs

> The runtime system always executes the statements within the finally block regardless of what happens within the try block. So it's the perfect place to perform cleanup.

```
BufferedReader in
       = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     try {
        while((thisLine=in.readLine())!=null){
        ...  
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
                    //in.close();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
       in.close
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    // stuff here
} finally {
    try {
        in.close()
    } catch (IOException e) {} // ignore
}
```